# Redirect 404 and 500 Errors in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to get 404 and 500 errors to redirect to my homepage.

So far I have this in `Startup.cs`, which works fine, but redirects all error codes >=400 (I want to handle Bad Requests differently):

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/?error={0}");
```

Everything I read tells me this is the answer:

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    await next();
    if ((ctx.Response.StatusCode == 404 || ctx.Response.StatusCode == 500) && !ctx.Response.HasStarted)
    {
        ctx.Request.Path = "/?error=" + ctx.Response.StatusCode;
        await next();
    }
});
```

But it doesn't redirect, I'm just presented with a blank 404 page and remain on the made-up url I entered.

With a breakpoint on `ctx.Request.Path = ...` I can see the code is hit; it just doesn't redirect.

Any ideas what I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have put UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects before async code block? I have copy your code in my project, it can redirect to https://localhost:5001/?error=500

Comment: No, removed that line in favour of the new code - I assume that's correct

Comment: Yeah, I can step into async code block. Maybe, UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirrcts is reduced.